# Webmaster Tools: Network Unreachable - IPv6 Problem?

Tags: domain-name-system, google

since I have installed W3 Total Cache I constantly get "Network unreachable" errors for ONLY about 3-4 random pages on a domain per day. This is unacceptable and I need to solve it even if it's only 3-4 pages.

The only error I see in /var/log/messages is

```
 printk: 2 messages suppressed.
```

And then when I restarted "named" (I rarely do) I get the message

```
**network unreachable resolving '137.7.24.188.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN':** 2001:610:240:0:53::193#53: 1 Time(s)
```

Do you think the problem is related to the installation of W3 Total Cache or could it be because I started named without adding ""OPTIONS="-4"" and therefore allowing IPv6

I heard Google is already using IPv6

I am very grateful for any response, because I no longer have any idea what I could do.

Comment: Are the errors on pages that are on domains with IPv6 records?

Comment: Nope. Some random pages. My new theory is that Apache was causing the problem. Every 2 hour a graceful restart. To solve that in WHM go to Statistics and change Bandwith processing from 2 to 24. Another reason for high traffic sites might be log rotation, I changed the Log rotation threshold to 1GB from 300MB to avoid restarts. Will keep you posted

Comment: "Network unreachable" seems like a *really* weird error to get for an Apache restart.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disabling the entire IPv6 module is not recommend according to CentOS FAQ

Instead do this:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`

If it says 0 then do this:

Add to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then open up /etc/sysconfig/named.conf and add

```
OPTIONS="-4"
```

Comment: This answer really has nothing to do with the question...

Answer (score 1):

Does your server have working IPv6 connectivity to the internet?

Looks like it's trying to resolve that address via an IPv6 name server, and it's unable to do so.